# jTable não adiciona a segunda string que eu coloquei numa array

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Eu criei uma array com dois valores e queria colocar ela numa tabela... com um botão inserir (inserir várias linhas)
1- eu declarei a string linha[] e os valores abaixo;
2- achei que um 'for each' fosse resolver, adicionando uma linha (add.row) a cada passada.
mas nao.
3- para teste, o sout esta ok.
4 como resultado,ele imprime duas vezes a primeira string "primeira linha"

```
String[] linha = {"primeira linha", "segunda linha"};
  for(String linhas : linha){
    ((DefaultTableModel) jTable.getModel()).addRow(linha);
    System.out.println(linha);
  }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

para remover as linhas, eu fiz isso aqui e resolveu;
pois se trata de "int" no "removeRow"

```
// limpar todas as linhas da tabela jTable
        for(int i = jTable.getRowCount(); i>0 ; i--){
            ((DefaultTableModel) jTable.getModel()).removeRow(0);
        }
```

Comment: Traduza a pergunta, Luke. Do contrário ela será fechada

Comment: eu ja saquei que no foreach eu tenho que usar a string "linhas" mas o addRow pede um object array... portanto não sei como.

Comment: tentei esse aqui também
```
String[] linha = {"primeira linha","segunda linha"};
        for (int i = 0 ; i<linha.length ; i++){
            ((DefaultTableModel) jTableListaObstaculos.getModel()).addRow(linha);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro está no foreach

```
String[] linha = {"primeira linha", "segunda linha"};
for(String linhas : linha){
((DefaultTableModel) jTable.getModel()).addRow(linha);
System.out.println(linha);
}
```

Na terceira linha voce está adicionando o **ARRAY LINHA**, e não o **elemento linhas** como você queria fazer.O método está acessando diretamente o array e pegando o primeiro elemento somente. 
Para corrigir basta trocar **linha** por **linhas** dentro dos comandos do **foreach**:

```
String[] linha = {"primeira linha", "segunda linha"};
  for(String linhas : linha){
    ((DefaultTableModel) jTable.getModel()).addRow(linhas);
    System.out.println(linhas);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ola,

Você pode inicializar o JTable de outra forma, passando um array com as colunas, e um array com os dados (que voce pode montar com o que voce precisa)
Adicione tambem o Jtable em um JScrollPane para exibir o header das colunas

Fica parecido com isso

```
String[] colunas = new String[] { "Nome", "Sobrenome", "Idade" };

Object[][] dados = new Object[][] { { "Jose", "Silva", 44 }, { "Manuel", "Bento", 44 }, };

JTable table = new JTable(dados, colunas);

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: ele só adiciona o "primeira linha" na tabela